# Trying to access unique records and the records of those unique records from the same table

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

```
select Id, Name from sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c where Name in (select Name from sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c group by Name LIMIT 3)
```

I am not sure how to explain what I am trying to get here. In the above query I want all records from table based on the unique records from a column in the same table. Is this something that can be achieved in SOQL? The table that we are accessing has a column varied count of unique records in a column.

[image]
Plz advise.

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the count of records for each value in the Name field? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @David Thats almost right, but not the count of records but the actual records of values in Name field. I got the original post edited with the example table, In that image the unit count varies for each building. I am trying to get the records of each building for example here the buildings would be 10 highwater path & 248 Hanover st in one single soql call.

Comment: So you just want the unique values of the Name field across all records?

Comment: @David, in the above soql the inner would get us 2 records - 10 highwater path & 248 hanover st based on the above table. 10 highwaterpath has 8 records and 248 hanover st has 4 records. The outer soql should get us all the records for each record that was output by the inner query.

Comment: How is that different from querying the whole table? Do you want to output only the rows that have a Name value that is *shared* with other records?

Comment: The table I am querying has more than 100,000 records. Querying the whole table was what I did in the beginning. Since we do not know where to put a limit as buildings have different total number of units. For e.g if I write a query like select Id, Name from table group by Name LIMIT 2, this might get cut off at the mid point of a building.

Comment: OK, so you want to get back row-level detail of the Units contained in specific Buildings, where the Building is identified by the Name field. How do you know which Buildings you want?

Comment: @David that's exactly what I am looking for. I would be pulling in all buildings, but pulling in all the buildings in one soql, I believe it would be resource consuming, so that's why I have the limit.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to group all records by name and then do something with the results, but I think we're missing something.  Could you say a little more about the use case?  That might help clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was plain sql you could use something like [DENSE_RANK()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

However or unfortunately this is not an option, perhaps doing something like an aggregate group by might do the trick for you?

```
SELECT StageName, COUNT(Id) FROM Opportunity GROUP BY StageName
```

The above group me 76000 opportunities into unique names:
[image]

This option is not ideal as you will be breaking best practices by doing queries inside a loop, however, as i mentioned the funtioned that you could use is not available in soql (I added the link as it will be nice for you to be familiar with it)

The aggregate example that i gave you will help you find unique names, then you can do something like below:

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT StageName, COUNT(Id) FROM Opportunity GROUP BY StageName];
System.debug(groupedResults.size());

List<sObject> result = new List<sObject>();
//I GUESS YOU CAN DECIDE THE NUMBER
if (groupedResults.size() <= 50) {
    for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
        String soql = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = \'' + ar.get('Name') + '\' LIMIT 1';
        System.debug(soql);
        sObject singleResult = new sObject();
        singleResult = Database.quer(soql);
        result.add(singleResult);
    }
}
```

Now if the result of the aggregate is too big (number of unique), you will definitely not be able to do this. I would do, (quick solution) is creating a custom object and save the records in there (When all conditions are met) perhaps I will add in there a unique field constrain, and I will query directly this object.

Comment: I am not looking for the count, but actual records, as each record has varied column information.

Comment: I just edit and add to my answer a more complete solution that hopefully help you visualize a possible solution by using this aggregate query

Comment: Did it help the answer? will be interesting to know how you end up doing it

Comment: I used yours, it worked, then went with a more leaner version which was Davids.. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, i am glad. Can I ask with the solution of @david wouldnt you get more than 1 record with the same name? perhaps I misunderstood the question, but is always nice to learn other approaches :)

Comment: No you won't get more than one record with the same name

Answer (score 1):

You can't end-run around the transaction SOQL rows limit this way.

Essentially, you have two choices here:

One, you can use a SOQL Aggregate Query, which will yield you fields that are grouped and aggregated *only* - not row-level details. When you run an aggregate query, you're charged against your 50,000 row limit only the count of aggregate line items that are returned.

To make this concrete, you can do

```
select count(), Name from sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c GROUP BY Name
```

to get back a `List<AggregateResult>` containing the count of records sharing each `Name` value. You'd be charged SOQL rows against your limit equal to the number of aggregate line items returned, i.e., the number of unique `Name` values. You *cannot* get back details on the rows that are aggregated when you use an aggregate query.

The other option is to filter your query to reduce the total number of rows returned, *without* using aggregate functions. That's the only way you'll get row-level detail (rather than aggregate detail), but the downside is that you are charged every single row returned against your 50,000 row limit.

Again, to make this concrete, you could filter your query by doing something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c where Name in ('Name', 'Other Name', 'A third name')
```

If what you really want is to find all of the records whose Name value is shared with some other number of records, you'll have to run two separate queries: one aggregate and one not:

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
List<AggregateResult> ars = [SELECT Name FROM sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Id) > 3];
for (AggregateResult ar : ars) {
    names.add(ar.get('expr0'));
}

List<sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c> records;
records = [SELECT Id, Name FROM sumchans__AddressReportMATeam__c where Name in :names];
```

That will get your the line-level detail of records whose Name is shared with a total of more than 3 records. It'll cost you one row per Name that matches those conditions (for the aggregate query) plus one row per record having that Name (from the non-aggregate query).

Comment: Thanks @David. very nicely explained, actually I was having questions about the limits as well, which I was reading through. just wondering if I could group by 3 fields in the first soql and in the second soql retrieve those records with multiple where in fields.

Comment: @Sumchans I think you are overcomplicating this, and we might be getting into x-y problem territory.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, I am sorry, just want the code to be foolproof.

Comment: Totally understood. Happy to support that objective! In general, you'll find that you can't gimmick the limits (there are a few exceptions). It's better to structure your code differently to work within them, even when that may force painful changes in the approach. Feel free to ask more questions to refine this issue, but just keep in mind that folks are having a hard time understanding exactly what you're trying to do here.